# Search for dollar amounts with grep

Tags: grep

I'm using suggestions found in another thread and *none* of them seem to find what I'm looking for.

Sample text string is one within a very large table:

```
$25 to $175 or $105.50 for XXxxxx‑covered services
```

I want to add carats around *all* $amounts as shown here:

```
<$25> to <$175> or <$105.50> for XXxxxx‑covered services
```

Comment: And your question is?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out!!!!

GREP searched for 
\$\d+    Finds $amounts without decimals 
\$\d+.\d+    Finds $amounts including decimals

Replace with

Is there a way to search/replace for amounts BOTH with and without decimals?
So far, found \$\d+| \$\d+.\d+
which finds both, but only with a space before the dollar sign with decimals... without the space after the "or" symbol, it only finds digits before the decimal.

Comment: You might want to escape that dot in `\$\d+.\d+` – dot represents "any character" in regex, so it would match things like `$00X00`, it they would appear. Just add a backslash: `\$\d+\.\d+`.

Answer (score 0):

You could use the following regex

```
\$[0-9]*.?[0-9]{2}
```

You could replace [0-9] with \d

The ? means that the . can be present 0 or 1 time.

**EDIT**

As you seem to be a rookie with regex you should use this website to learn more about them.
https://regex101.com/

Comment: OMG. PERFECT. Thank you!

Comment: Do you have a similar solution for adding searching percentages — from 0% up to 100%?

Comment: [0-9]*\.?[0-9]*\% But you should take a look at my original answer to have more informations. If you could accept my answer that would be great.